# creating a view for query result as xml and ssms

Tags: ssms

I want to create a bunch of views to return a data as an xml for playing with xsl-fo.
This is not a problem at all, I know how to create such view, but I have a problem in the SQL Server Management Studio. To return the xml through view, I have to add an alias for the result column. However when I do that, I can't preview the returned xml in additional window in the SSMS any more.
e.g
When I'm not using the alias, in the result, the data this is a link which I can click to show the formatted xml in additional window:
[image]

With alias I can't do that:

[image]

I have a big xml in result, so I need the functionality to preview them. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to cast this to xml type.